# Android return from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So, I'm a bit of a new Android dev, but I'm making progress. I have a `MainActivity` which is what I boot to, and then a set of sub activities to do some work.

I'm currently working to get those sub activities to time out and return to `MainActivity` to avoid sitting on some random window forever. It's sort of a `Kiosk` type app I'm working on, so going back to `MainActivity` is a requirement.

I have been able to make this work with a `Handler and Runnable()` in my sub activity class. If I do the following when the handler times out and `Runnable.run()` is called, it works, sort of.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LightsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, this causes MainActivity to run `onCreate` again. Since MainActivity is running in the background already, I want to return to that instance instead of starting a new one.

What I think I want to do is call `finish()` in the Runnable and have it close the activity and go back to Main. This doesn't work right. I see MainActivity `onStart()` runs, and not `onCreate()`, which is what I want.

However, what shows on the screen is the LightsActivity design layout, but without the `LightsActivity` class actually running. I have some timers created in `LightsActivity.onCreate()` which update fields every second when it's running, but those stop working after I call `finish()` (again, expected). What's the trick to stopping an Activity class, and changing the UI back to the `MainActivity` window?

I am doing something wrong or this is a bug. All of the documents say `finish()` should do what I want. Note that calling `LightsActivity.this.finish()` doesn't work in Runnable either, so it's not a scoping issue I don't think.

Hoping someone with a lot of Android experience can help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
    }

    public void viewLights(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Managing the lights");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);
        startActivity(m_lights);
    }
}

public class LightsActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = LightsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);
        handler.postDelayed(finalizer, 1000 * 10);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    Runnable finalizer = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity timed out");
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

And I get the following output. I can reproduce with this simple example, all other code commented out.

```
07-19 13:20:37.761 1363-1363/? D/MainActivity: onCreate()
07-19 13:20:37.767 1363-1363/? D/MainActivity: onStart
07-19 13:21:20.280 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/MainActivity: Managing the lights
07-19 13:21:20.569 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/LightsActivity: onCreate()
07-19 13:21:20.571 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/LightsActivity: onStart
07-19 13:21:21.089 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/MainActivity: onStop
07-19 13:21:30.579 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/LightsActivity: Activity timed out
07-19 13:21:30.615 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/MainActivity: onStart
07-19 13:21:31.100 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/LightsActivity: onStop
07-19 13:21:31.100 1363-1363/com.home.pete.aquarium D/LightsActivity: onDestroy
```

The LightsActivity screen is still showing, not the MainActivity.

Comment: Sorry, yes, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] of all related code?

Comment: I don't think I can post a full Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable here. The code itself I know how to post won't build without a lot of Android Studio necessary work. However, you can see the complete source at my https://github.com/buelowp/aquarium page. You should be able to check that out and build it directly.

Comment: I'm not really interested in building your source code in order to try to understand what you're asking, sorry. To briefly answer question: you go back to previous activities using finish(). You request data to be returned starting with startActivityForResult(). Regarding the Runnable/Handler, you should ideally stop those during onPause() and resume in onStart(), which is what's executed when you resume the Activity, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I think I want to do is call finish() in the Runnable and have it close the activity and go back to Main. This doesn't work right. I see MainActivity onStart() runs, and not onCreate(), which is what I want.

That is working right. Review the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

1. You start `MainActivity` -> `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`
2. You start `LightsActivity` -> `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`
3. Meanwhile, `MainActivity` goes into the background -> `onPause`, `onStop`
4. Finish `LightsActivity` -> `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`
5. `MainActivity` -> `onStart`, `onResume`

> However, what shows on the screen is the LightsActivity design layout, but without the LightsActivity class actually running. I have some timers created in LightsActivity.onCreate() which update fields every second when it's running, but those stop working after I call finish() (again, expected). What's the trick to stopping an Activity class, and changing the UI back to the MainActivity window?

What you describe should work. If not, you have a bug. But without code, screenshots, stacktrace, etc, no one can say what you're doing wrong. Put logging statements in your lifecycle methods and calls to `finish` and trace through the steps.

UPDATE:

Well here's your problem:

```
public void viewLights(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Managing the lights");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);
    startActivity(m_lights);
}
```

This says, in `MainActivity`, when navigating to the `ViewLightsActivity`, first set the content view to the layout of `activity_lights` (overriding `MainActivity`'s layout), then navigate to the `LightsActivity`.

So of course when you return to the Activity, it has the new layout you previously set. Remove the call to `setContentView` in this method. You should only ever call `setContentView` in `onCreate` unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: I agree it should, but I posted a stripped down example without other code inside, and it still doesn't work right. I'm wondering if this is a bug in AT, but I can't find anyone else complaining about it on the AT Google+ site, and that group complains about a lot.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I got that from a google howto for Things a while back. I see it now why that wouldn't make sense though.